# Data is Update on reinstall that App (Swift)

Tags: ios, rest, web-services, swift3, xcode8

I use Bussiness Manager & Download Manager to fetch the data from web services .Data is not updating on whole app until App will reinstall on the Device . I also use viewDidAppear Method but it also not working . This is serious issue to me please help me by share your experience .Thanks in advance

Bussiness Manager Method

```
     class func addNewAddressToProfile(_ values:String , completionHandler:@escaping (_ result:NSDictionary)->())
     {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated).async {

        let result = DownloadManager.downloadDataFromServer(NSString(format:"%@", values) as String, urlString: "https://abc.php") as NSDictionary

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completionHandler(result)
        }
       }
     }

    class func getProfileInformation(_ userID:String , completionHandler:@escaping (_ result:NSDictionary)->())
    {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated).async {

        let url = NSString(format: "https://www.zabrabox.com/api.php?rquest=get_customer_address&customer_id=%@",userID)
        let result = DownloadManager.downloadDataFromServerGetMethod(url as String) as NSDictionary
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completionHandler(result)
        }
       }
      }
```

Download Manager Method

```
     class func downloadDataFromServer(_ parameter:String , urlString: String) ->NSDictionary
     {

    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    urlRequest.url = URL(string: urlString)
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Disposition")
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    let data = (parameter as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    urlRequest.httpBody = data

    var Error:NSError? = nil

    var returnData: Data?
    do {
        returnData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(urlRequest as URLRequest, returning: nil)


    } catch let error as NSError {
        Error = error
        returnData = nil
   }

    if(Error == nil)
    {
        return self.validateResponds(returnData!)
    }
    let errorResult:NSDictionary = [
        "status" : "401",
        "message" : "Error message"
    ]

    return errorResult
}
```

her is my viewDidAppear method

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: kUserDetails) as! Data
    let userDic = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! NSDictionary
    userIDStr = userDic.value(forKey: "customer_id") as! String

    print(userIDStr)

    BusinessManager.getProfileInformation(userIDStr, completionHandler: { (result) -> () in
        print(result)

        //        print(self.addressAry)
                    self.addressAry = result.value(forKey: "customer_address") as!
        NSMutableArray
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    let tempData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.addressAry)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(tempData, forKey: kAddToWishlist)

    })
}
```

Comment: Where are you reloading all your viewController components?

Comment: in viewDidAppearMethod .

Comment: You should also add that code to better understand your issue.

Comment: @waliyan: Can u show us how are u calling addNewAddressToProfile and what are you doing in the completion block of addNewAddressToProfile

Comment: @Sandeep my whole app services is not updating it just a single method that i shows.

Comment: @waliyan : are u sure result.value(forKey: "customer_address") as! NSMutableArray has some data ??

Comment: yes , I am Sure and i also print it every time

Comment: But that is not updated . It shows that data which were at the login time

Comment: @waliyan : Can you show us tableView data source methods like number of rows in section/cellforrowAtIndexPath etc and please delete ur answer as its not the correct answer u'll receive down vote soon

Comment: @Sandeep ,Rest of the thing working properly , please suggest that the UserDefaults is right to save the data , is there is any problem with userDefaults or it's correct.

Comment: @waliyan : is your print(userIDStr) is printing proper string then its fine

Comment: Yes print(userIDStr) is printing proper

Comment: Like @SandeepBhandari said, share the UITableViewDatasource implementation. Indenting your code also helps, makes it easy to read

Comment: @Lukas , I check response there , I used addressAry which mention above to show the data on table view and I also mention that Data is update when I reinstall the app after deleting it.

Comment: print self.addressAry before you call reload and see if its populated as you expect it

Comment: Any Body suggest me that how to refresh data into the NSUserdefault variable , I think that could be the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have to clear cookies and cache by using this code..

```
 URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()

    if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
        for cookie in cookies {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the Answer , I used the code for clear cookies and cache for whole App and Thats workings . Thanks for the contribution